# mysql result to be seen only to friend id

Tags: php, mysql

I'am making a query in which I want to select those records which when a user logged in cannot see but his friend can see it . i. e. a notification in which jhon doe updates his status and vikram should see it not john doe . can any one help in this

here is the query

```
select * 
from notification 
where title_text='Global Notification'
      and user_id=3 and owner_user_id  != 3 and is_seen=0  
order by time_stamp desc
```

Here `user id` is the one who is logged in.
and `owner_user_id` is the one who made the status update

So when john doe made a update (`owner_user_id`) only vikram should see it (`user_id`) not johndoe

Comment: so is that query not working...?

Comment: nopes its showing no results and if i use or it is visisble to all of the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first use integers for messages status (`title_text` should be something like `message_type`), it will be faster for database.

Next step: if You want to create status system, try to do something like mail system, it'll have fields like these: `id`,`from_id`,`to_id`,`message_type`,`message`,`time_stamp`, `status`. Your friend's status will be added to this table like
`NULL,3,15,1,1,'blablabla','2012-01-13 11:44:00',0`

Next step get all notification (message_type=1, for example)

```
SELECT * FROM 'my_messages' WHERE to_id=15 AND message_type=1 AND status=0 ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

You'll get all new(status=0) notifications(message_type=1) for current user(to_id=15)

If You want to create a public statuses, You shouldn't check access to them in WHERE clause. Create array of users that You read and select their statuses You didn't read(save read statuses to COOKIE):

```
$myFriends = array(4,17,69,254,1,24); // users id
$iHaveRead = array(12,55,1245,1245,1243); // messages id


$myNotification = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM 'my_notifications'
WHERE 
owner_user_id IN (".implode(',',$myFriends).") 
AND 
time_stamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND
id NOT IN (".implode(',',iHaveRead ).") 
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
");
```

This query will return all unread Your friends' statuses in 1 month

Comment: thanks for helping out friend on behaf of your query i got a huge idea of how to do it . instead of implode i used union can u help me out in this code there seem to be a error ...$sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ( ('select * from notification where title_text='Global Notification' `user_id`=$frnnid and `owner_user_id`=$frnnid and `is_seen`=0 order by `time_stamp` desc') union ('select * from notification where title_text='Global Notification'  and user_id=$id and  owner_user_id=$frnnid and is_seen=0  order by time_stamp desc')) notification order by Desc");

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from notification 
where title_text='Global Notification'
      and user_id=3 and owner_user_id  <> 3 and is_seen=0  
order by time_stamp desc
```

Comment: no friend this will get only the updates done for john doe not the one which vikram updated on his profile

Comment: in this case 3 is vikram , its right vikram is not seeying his updated notification , but when i chnage the id to 6 which is of john doe , john doe is also not able to see it ???? i tried thz before , ny more ideads friend , thanks for replying